# Hangfire configuration - how often it pings the database

Tags: hangfire

It looks like Hangfire hits the database few times a second, probably to find out if there are any jobs to pick up. I would like to slow it down as I don't mind if the checks are done every few seconds.

Is it possible?

Hangfire 1.6 docs say:

> The usage is simple, just include Hangfire namespace in your application initialization class and discover extension methods for the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration property.

I cannot find anything that would help me here :(

Answer (score 1):

Look at this : http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html#configuring-the-polling-interval

`var options = new SqlServerStorageOptions{
    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15) // Default value};
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("<name or connection string>", options);`